# Firebase Database Update profile picture on every post in firebase recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, android-recyclerview

I have a feed with posts from different users that is built using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

It works fine but when i change a user's profile picture i want the profile picture from all of that user's posts to change as well.

At the moment it just displays the profile picture that was present at the moment the post was created.

Here is the code:

I call chooseImage when i click the upload button:

```
private void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            uploadImage();
        }
    }

private void uploadImage() {
        if (imageUri != null) {

            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "." + getImageExtension(imageUri));
            fileReference.putFile(imageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(imgProfile);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            }, 1000);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image changed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            databaseReference.child("profilePic").setValue(taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setPhotoUri(imageUri)
                                    .build();
                            user.updateProfile(profileChangeRequest);

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

This is how i add the posts:

```
btnPostComm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String story = et.getText().toString();
                String title = et2.getText().toString();
                String key = refference.push().getKey();
                String name = user.getDisplayName();
                String uri = user.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                CommModel model = new CommModel(
                        story,
                        title,
                        name,
                        uri
                );

                refference
                        .child(key)
                        .setValue(model);
            }
        });
```

This is my Model class:

```
public class CommModel {
    private String story;
    private String title;
    private String name;
    private String uri;

    public CommModel(){}

    public CommModel(String story, String title, String name, String uri) {
        this.story = story;
        this.title = title;
        this.name = name;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getStory() {
        return story;
    }

    public void setStory(String story) {
        this.story = story;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

This is the ViewHolder:

```
public class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtStory;
    public TextView txtTitle;
    public TextView txtName;
    public CircularImageView proImage;

    public QNAViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtStory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStory);
        txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName1);
        proImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile3);
    }
}
```

And this is the Adapter in the Fragment that hosts the RecyclerView:

```
public void showPosts() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CommModel>()
                .setQuery(ref, CommModel.class)
                .build();
        adpt = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CommModel, PostsViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CommModel model) {
                holder.txtStory.setText(model.getStory());
                holder.txtTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
                holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());
                Glide.with(Posts.this).load(model.getUri()).into(holder.proImage);

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return super.getItemCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                super.onDataChanged();
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CommModel getItem(int position) {
                return super.getItem(getItemCount() - 1 - position);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.qna_feed, parent, false);
                return new PostsViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adpt.startListening();
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adpt);
    }
```

How can i update the pictures on every post of a user when he changes his profile pic?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that, you have to change the `CommModel` class. You need to add another property, such as `userUid`.

```
private String story;
private String title;
private String name;
private String uri;
private String userUid; //Create new one and getter setter too
```

After that, at your `showPosts` method, you can call the user's property and get his profile picture.

```
holder.txtStory.setText(model.getStory());
holder.txtTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());

final String userUid = model.getUserUid();
//Call Firebase to get user current profile.
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if(dataSnapshot.exist()){
            final String pictureUrl = dataSnapshot.chilld("profilePic").getValue(String.class);
             Glide.with(Posts.this).load(pictureUrl).into(holder.proImage);
         }


      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a **Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String** error on line `final String profilePic = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` . My Users Database looks like this: Users -> name, email, phone, profilePic

Comment: One more mention though. In **uploadImage()** instead of `databaseReference.child("profilePic").setValue(taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString());` it should be `databaseReference.child("profilePic").setValue(imageUri.toString());`

Comment: It works with `setValue(imageUri.toString())` . `taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString()` was getting the wrong link to the image and there was nothing to load into the profile pic imageView.

Comment: I've encountered another problem. If i use the app from another device, the pictures are not loaded, the imageViews are empty. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @AdrianCosmin what do you mean not loaded? `profileUrl` no value?